# Como disponibilizar conteúdo para download em vez de exibir na página?

Tags: php, download

Tenho uma aplicação em PHP e uma URL de um arquivo. Gostaria que, quando o usuário clicasse em um botão qualquer, fizesse com que o navegador disparasse a ação para download ou abertura da janela de opções de download desse arquivo (no caso do Firefox).

O arquivo pode ser DE QUALQUER EXTENSÃO, como um código-fonte, um arquivo compactado ou multimídia.

Obs: Download no sentido, servidor -> usuário.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Se você simplesmente quer fazer o download de um arquivo existente basta colocar o atributo download na tag a:

```
<a href="caminho-ate-o-arquivo.txt" download>Clique aqui para fazer o download</a>
```

Se você deseja que o download seja feito no momento que a página é carregada, basta fazer isso:

```
<?php

    // Define o tempo máximo de execução em 0 para as conexões lentas
    set_time_limit(0);
    // Arqui você faz as validações e/ou pega os dados do banco de dados
    $aquivoNome = 'imagem.jpg'; // nome do arquivo que será enviado p/ download
    $arquivoLocal = '/pasta/do/arquivo/'.$aquivoNome; // caminho absoluto do arquivo
    // Verifica se o arquivo não existe
    if (!file_exists($arquivoLocal)) {
    // Exiba uma mensagem de erro caso ele não exista
    exit;
    }
    // Aqui você pode aumentar o contador de downloads
    // Definimos o novo nome do arquivo
    $novoNome = 'imagem_nova.jpg';
    // Configuramos os headers que serão enviados para o browser
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$novoNome.'"');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($aquivoNome));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    // Envia o arquivo para o cliente
    readfile($aquivoNome);
?>
```

[Fonte](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/forcando-o-download-de-arquivos-com-php)

Comment: Show @Adriano de Azevedo, me ajudou muito com essa dica, valeu