# como forçar o download de um arquivo em php e deleta-lo logo em seguida

Tags: php, arquivo, variáveis, download, delete

fiz um arquivo com a função fopen(); e preciso que ele seja baixado no computador do usuário e deletado logo em seguida, e é necessário que o nome do arquivo esteja em uma variável, pois o nome do arquivo irá variar dependendo do usuário.

Comment: Pode mostrar seu código e o que não funciona?

Comment: use unlink("diretorio/nomeaequivo.ext"); ou se estiver na pasta unlink("nomeaequivo.ext");

Comment: relacionada https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114254/download-de-arquivos-em-php

Comment: atributo download do html5   https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp