# Como disponibilizar arquivos para download em PHP?

Tags: php

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível criar arquivos dinamicamente e disponibilizá-los para download em PHP.

Basicamente, estou recuperando alguns dados do Banco, e minha ideia era criar automaticamente um arquivo com estas informações, permitindo ao usuário poder baixar o arquivo em questão (que não seja de uma maneira forçada).

Comment: acho que é possivel com o atributo download em um link, <a href="" download>

Comment: aqui vc encontra um script de download com php https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114254/download-de-arquivos-em-php